# Advance excel formula

Tags: excel, testing, excel-formula, formula, index-match

[I want answer of that question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zQ9Wj.jpg)

I want answer for that question because I was tried many times. In this question they want the value for product in each quarter with the help of each direction. The directions are east west north south.

Comment: Did you try `INDEX()/MATCH()` function? Post data as text table so that we can copy.

Comment: Can you elaborate your words because I'm not getting your point that what are your saying instead please can you send me after applying the formula in sheet

Comment: When you give the data in a format that we can copy / paste then more of us might play - at  the moment we may not have time to do typing for you.

Comment: I fixed the formula and the picture to put the number in correct order. Check it now.

Comment: Index with match works well: INDEX($B$3:$E$8,MATCH($A$11,$A$3:$A$8,0),MATCH($D13,$B$2:$E$2,0)) but you have to sort one array for each East West etc.

Comment: Your question should be posted in a way that somebody visiting this site with a similar problem could find an answer here.

The way you posted is:
dump a picture and ask for answer.
The way you could better post: 
Explain your goal,
Post dummy data as markdown table to reproduce your problem,
Explain what result you expect with the sample data,
Show formula(s) you tried yourself and explain why you expect it to work, but you get a different result.

This comment probably took me more time than you posting the question.
Remember: we're here to help, but you need to help us help you.

Answer (score 4):

```
=WRAPCOLS(XLOOKUP(I10,A3:A8,B3:Q8),4)
```

[image]

Comment: Like this, neat.

Comment: The answer is wrong because I want the result quarter wise in horizontal manner but your formula is giving me vertical values which are wrong.

Comment: @Gauravlodhi So East : Chocolates : Q1 is 86, and the other values for chocolates that I check are also correct... This matches the framework that you provided for the results so why is it wrong in your opinion?

Comment: Ok , I just fixed it to show correctly. check it out.

Comment: Thanks Cary you nailed my problem. Thanks for your valuable help.

Comment: If only the question itself was described in an instance of the brilliance of this answer it would've been a good question.

Answer (score 0):

For any NON-Office 365 users out there, this can also be achieved with INDEX/MATCH, using the secondary syntax for INDEX (reference, row_num, [column_num], [area_num]).

Build the *reference* parameter by selecting each area of the data range individually for East, West, North and South, separated by commas and enclosed in brackets:

```
=INDEX((C3:F8,G3:J8,K3:N8,O3:R8), row_num, [column_num], [area_num])
```

To solve for the *row_num*, *[column_num]*, and *[area_num]* parameters, use the MATCH function:

```
=INDEX((C3:F8,G3:J8,K3:N8,O3:R8), MATCH(I10,B3:B8,0), MATCH(G13:G16,C2:F2,0), MATCH(H12:K12,H12:K12,0))
```

Since the lookup values for *[column_num]* and *[area_num]* are in the same order as the source table, array constants can be used to simplify the formula:

```
=INDEX((C3:F8,G3:J8,K3:N8,O3:R8), MATCH(I10,B3:B8,0), {1;2;3;4}, {1,2,3,4})
```

To make this work in older versions of Excel, first select the entire output range H13:K16, type the formula and press Ctrl+Shift+Enter.